# Add a missing single node using VBA

Tags: xml, vba

**Target:** Using VBA, I need to check if a certain node is missing and add the node as explained below.

- I need to find the missing single node **PartId1** and add the value `31245678934`
- The value will remain constant for **PartId1** node. If you observe the below xml, it's the second **`Del`** node having a missing `PartId1`. So I need to add it using VBA.
- Please note that `PartId1` should be included **after** **`Partid`**, if missing.

---

This is how my xml file looks like:

```
<Document>
        <Document xmlns="iso">
            <SalesInstrument>
                <Sales>
                    <Del>
                        <PartId>123456</PartId>
                        <PartId1>31245678934</PartId1>
                        <PartId2>333661144</PartId2>
                    </Del>
                </Sales>
                <Sales>
                    <Del>
                        <PartId>456214</PartId>
                        <PartId2>333661144</PartId2>
                    </Del>
                </Sales>
                <Sales>
                    <Del>
                        <PartId>524752</PartId>
                        <PartId1>31245678934</PartId1>
                        <PartId2>333661144</PartId2>
                    </Del>
                </Sales>
            </ SalesInstrument >
</Document>
```

Here is the VBA Code I have so far

```
Sub TestXML()

    Dim XDoc                    As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim element                 As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim PartId                  As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim elements                As IXMLDOMSelection
    Dim xmlPath                 As String
    
    Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    XDoc.async = False
    XDoc.validateOnParse = True
    
    xmlPath = "C:\DelCxl.xml"
    
    If Not XDoc.Load(xmlPath) Then
        MsgBox XDoc.parseError.reason, vbOKOnly, "Error " & XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' all paths that end in element
    Set elements = XDoc.SelectNodes("//Del")
  

    ' loop through each element and try getting its PartId1
    Dim r As Long
    For Each element In elements
        Set PartId1 = element.SelectSingleNode("PartId1")
        If PartId1 Is Nothing Then
            ' element missing so add it here - need help here <<<
        End If
    Next element
    XDoc.Save (xmlPath)
    Set XDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Posted a commented solution to your question. Feel free to mark as answered &/or to upvote if helpful.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the current MSXML2 version 6.0 (needs library reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0) to load a wellformed xml document - *see further note below*. As you use a namespace, you'll have to provide for in section a).
- I'd suggest to select `Del` node(s) *without* a `PartId1` node directly via the following XPath
  (note the chosen namespace prefix `i:`):

```
   XDoc.SelectNodes("//i:Del[not(i:PartId1)]")
```

- This allows to insert the new content immediately via `InsertBefore`.
  (Only in case of a missing neighbour tag `PartId2` I use `AppendChild`)
- *If you prefer a pretty xml layout with line breaks and indentation,
  you may activate the outmarked code lines in section e)*.

```
Sub TestXML()
    Const Lvl As Long = 5   ' Hierarchy level of PartId1 needed for optional indentation
'a) set xmlL document to memory (version 6.0, providing for namespace)
    Dim XDoc    As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    XDoc.async = False
    XDoc.validateOnParse = True
    XDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:i=""iso"""
'b) load xml
    Dim xmlPath As String
    xmlPath = "C:\DelCxl.xml"
    If Not XDoc.Load(xmlPath) Then
        MsgBox XDoc.parseError.reason, vbOKOnly, "Error " & XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode
        Exit Sub
    End If
'c) get (all) Del elements without a PartId1 node
    Dim elements As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList 'As IXMLDOMSelection
    Set elements = XDoc.SelectNodes("//i:Del[not(i:PartId1)]")
'd) define fixed node plus text content
    Dim newChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    ' pass XML namespace argument for all elements you add to the DOM!
    Set newChild = XDoc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "PartId1", "iso")
    newChild.Text = "31245678934"
'e) insert PartId2 as new Child node below found Del node(s)
    Dim element As IXMLDOMElement
    For Each element In elements
        'check for existing PartId2 as expected sibling
        Dim PartId2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
        Set PartId2 = element.SelectSingleNode("i:PartId2") ' identified by chosen namespace prefix
        If PartId2 Is Nothing Then
            ''optional indentation
            'element.appendChild XDoc.createTextNode(Chr(13) & Chr(10) & String(5, vbTab))
            element.appendChild newChild
        Else    ' insert before found PartId2 node
            ''optional indentations
            'element.InsertBefore XDoc.createTextNode(Chr(13) & Chr(10) & String(5, vbTab)), PartId2
            element.InsertBefore newChild, PartId2
            'element.InsertBefore XDoc.createTextNode(Chr(13) & Chr(10) & String(5, vbTab)), PartId2
        End If
    Next element
    'Debug.Print XDoc.xml
'f) save xml
    XDoc.Save (xmlPath)
    ' Debug.Print XDoc.xml
    ''Set XDoc = Nothing    ' not needed as memory gets freed at procedure end anyway
End Sub
```

**Further note**

As the xml as shown in OP isn't **well-formed**, I *did assume* a closing `</Document>` node tag
as well as (the closing) `</SalesInstrument>` tag **without** a space after the slash:

```
<Document>
        <Document xmlns="iso">
            <SalesInstrument>
                <Sales>
                    <Del>
                        <PartId>123456</PartId>
                        <PartId1>31245678934</PartId1>
                        <PartId2>333661144</PartId2>
                    </Del>
                </Sales>
                <Sales>
                    <Del>
                        <PartId>456214</PartId>
                        <PartId2>333661144</PartId2>
                    </Del>
                </Sales>
                <Sales>
                    <Del>
                        <PartId>524752</PartId>
                        <PartId1>31245678934</PartId1>
                        <PartId2>333661144</PartId2>
                    </Del>
                </Sales>
            </SalesInstrument>
    </Document>
</Document>
```